# How do I detect a continuous ping connection in Windows 10 using native or Windows-maintained tools?

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet, ping

I have an IP provided by dedicated hardware connected via ethernet to a Windows computer. The ethernet connection has its own IP address. However, a manufacturer provided IP address is what I use to connect to the sensor and grab data.  I know what the IP is, the device is there, and I can pull data from it.

However, I cannot see the mapping between the ethernet IP and the sensor's data IP using the Windows tools `ipconfig` and `netstat`.  Additionally, I can't see the sensor's data IP even though I can hit it and pull data from it.

Since I'll be using multiple sensors on the same device, I'd like to be able to resolve which ethernet connection corresponds to which manufacturer provided, ascending IP address after everything is plugged in.

---

My idea right now is to:

1. continuously `ping -t` the data IP, which does respond with bytes
2. watch that `ping` with netstat and see which ethernet connection responds to the `ping`

The problem is that `netstat` either cannot see the `ping -t` command, or I am using it incorrectly.

What is the proper way to detect or watch what happens during a `ping -t IPADDR` command in Windows?

Note that method matters: it's not that I don't have *some* way to do this. I have adjacent solutions in python with `scapy` (3-12mb compiled, and I'm the only one comfortable w/ python) and can come up with something using `tshark`, but we'd rather not use `tshark` if we can avoid it. The goal is to detect the peripheral connection with powershell alone.

Comment: Have you considered using a packet sniffer?  That is what I would do.

Comment: Look at the routing table perhaps?

Comment: @John if I can rule out all alternative solutions than a packet sniffer, I think I'll get the go ahead. But my hope was this would somehow be possible in windows w/ native tools.  For more context, the reason I'm asking is because I have a system of devices connected to a bank of ethernet ports in a PICe NIC card, one of which maintains a "ping" connection to one of the other devices.  I'll need a way to detect my local ping test, and then use that same method to detect the remote ping that flows across the computer's internal network.  So this may be an XY problem, but ... 1/2

Comment: Why not run a trace route and just see the route your connection takes? `tracert 12.34.56.78`

Comment: @John I need due diligence that we absolutely need a packet sniffer -- whether it is `tshark`, `python` w/ `scapy`, or `go` w/ `gopacket`, etc.

Comment: @LPChip I'll give that a try -- that might solve a related problem (resolving the device IPs), but I'm not sure it'll prove that the device is alive and talking -- I'll still need to detect that things' persistent ping heartbeat, so I want to solve this sub problem of ping detection.

Comment: I use tracert to see the route, and paping (google for it, its on a google docs page) to ping a port and see if its alive or not. paping will work like telnet, it opens a tcp/ip connection to an ip:port, and if succesful, you get a green line with how long it took, just like ping, or a red line if it timed out.

Comment: paping: https://code.google.com/archive/p/paping/downloads

Comment: @LPChip trying it now...

Comment: @LPChip I think this'll work.  I'll leave the question up for a bit; it'll be a good boundary for what can be done w/ native windows alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more ways to accomplish this, but the method I'm comfortable with is the following:

The command `tracert hostname/ipaddress` can be used to see the route that is being taken from your ipaddress to the destination. Tracert is not limited to just your local network, and can also be used over the internet. It will ping each hop, and even though it can time out, it will continue on the route until the destination is reached.

For testing if a device is turned on, I use paping, which is available for download here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/paping/downloads

Paping is a cmd tool, you use it as follows:

`paping <destination ip> -p <port>` eg: `paping 12.34.56.78 -p 3389` or `paping google.com -p 80`

Comment: can tracert be configured to display the ip of the physical ethernet port used?

Comment: No, tracert does not support this. If you do IPv6, you can do a roundtrace though.

Comment: cool, a roundtrace with IPv6 is the Y solution for this.